# Find the real and imaginary terms of the function $z=\sin(x-iy)$

Tags: complex-numbers

If I have the function:
$$z=\sin(x-iy)$$
How do I find the real and imaginary parts of this function **without** relying on the hyperbolic identities?  In my attempt of this problem, I first used the trig identities to simplify this to: $$\sin(x)cos(iy)-cos(x)sin(iy)$$ but I am unsure how to continue from here without using the identities:

$$ \cos(iy) = \cosh(y), \quad    \sin(ib) = \sinh(y)$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use those identities? Which definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are you using?

Comment: We have not explicitly discussed those identities in lecture so I assume that I need to simplify this by another method.

Comment: But I do not get why not use the hyperbolics as by definition of using Euler identity below you get the hyperbolics out?

Comment: But how did you then define $\sin$ for complex numbers? If you did not use the Euler identity and did not use the $\cos(iy) = \cosh y$ identities, what did you do?

Comment: We were given $e^{ix} = cosx + isinx$ and that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use Eulers Formula for $\sin(x)$

$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

Derivation from Eulers Formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$:

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$
Equally we can plug in $-x$ for $x$ and use oddness of sine and evenness of cosine.
$$e^{-ix}=\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$$

Now subtract both equations to get the formula for $\sin(x)$. Adding both formulas will give you an analogue formula for cosine:
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Now let us apply this formula to $z=sin(x-iy)$

$$z=\frac{e^{i(x-iy)}-e^{-i(x-iy)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{ix+y}-e^{-ix-y}}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{e^ye^{ix}-e^{-y}e^{-ix}}{2i}=\frac{e^y[\cos(x)+i\sin(x)]-e^{-y}[\cos(x)-i\sin(x)]}{2i}$$

From here it should be easy to calculate the real and imaginary terms.

Comment: Could you explain where you got this formula for sin(x) from?  I understand it's derived from Euler's formula but I'm not grasping the direct connection.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand how you got the formula.  I'm still stuck, however, as to how to use this to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  You helped a lot in walking me through something I have essentially 0 experience with

Comment: You are welcome ;-). Just remember that "Euler is the Master of us all." :D!

Answer (score 4):

Notice, we can simplify as follows $$z=\sin(x-iy)$$
$$=\frac{e^{i(x-iy)}-e^{-i(x-iy)}}{2i}$$
$$=-i\left(\frac{e^{y+ix}-e^{-(y+ix)}}{2}\right)$$
$$=i\left(\frac{e^{-y}e^{-ix}-e^{y}e^{ix}}{2}\right)$$
$$=i\left(\frac{e^{-y}(\cos x-i\sin x)-e^{y}(\cos x+i\sin x)}{2}\right)$$
$$=i\left(\frac{(e^{-y}-e^{y})\cos x-i(e^{y}+e^{-y})\sin x}{2}\right)$$
$$=i\frac{(e^{-y}-e^{y})\cos x}{2}-i^2\frac{(e^{y}+e^{-y})\sin x}{2}$$
$$z=\frac{(e^{y}+e^{-y})}{2}\sin x+i\frac{(e^{-y}-e^{y})}{2}\cos x$$

Now, the real & the imaginary parts are as follows $$Re(z)=\color{red}{\frac{(e^{y}+e^{-y})}{2}\sin x}$$ 
$$Im(z)=\color{red}{\frac{(e^{-y}-e^{y})}{2}\cos x}$$